# The following webservice with the web service call does not work

Tags: php, jquery, web-services

I am trying to invoke a web service via some Jquery, but I am getting the following error

ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

When I try to access the web service via my browser, I get a response back,

https://vik-b-it.000webhostapp.com/intergration.php?primaryRef=1&amount=2&fp=3

{"fingerPrint":"1234|Hello|10|1|2|3"}

But when I call it through the following code I get the above error.. what am I missing here?

The Web service code is

```html
<?php

/* require the user as the parameter */
if(isset($_GET['primaryRef']) && isset($_GET['amount']) && isset($_GET['fp'])) 
{

 /*Set the variables */
 
 $primaryRef   = $_GET['primaryRef'];
 $amount   = $_GET['amount'];
 $fp    = $_GET['fp'];
 $merchantId  = 1234;
 $password   = 'Hello';
 $txnType   = 10;
 
 
 /* $results = 'This should be the return string'; */
 $results = $merchantId . '|' . $password . '|' . $txnType . '|' . $primaryRef .'|' . $amount .'|' . $fp;
 //$results = sha1($results);
 
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode(array('fingerPrint' =>$results));

 
}

?>
```

The Javascript code is

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  console.log('hello');
  
  GetFingerprint(1, 2, 3);
  
  function GetFingerprint(primaryRefNo, amount, fp){
  
 var divToBeWorkedOn = "#AjaxPlaceHolder";
    var webService = "https://vik-b-it.000webhostapp.com/intergration.php";
    var parameters = "{'primaryRef':'" + primaryRefNo + "','amount':'" + amount + "','fp':'" + fp + "'}";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: webService,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(e){
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");
        }
    });
}
  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

TEST PAGE

<div id='AjaxPlaceHolder'>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Thanks

If anyone is interested the final working code is as follows,

Webservice -->

```
   <?php
/* require the user as the parameter */
if(isset($_GET['primaryRef']) && isset($_GET['amount']) && isset($_GET['fp'])) 
{
    /*Set the variables */  
    $primaryRef     = $_GET['primaryRef'];
    $amount         = $_GET['amount'];
    $fp             = $_GET['fp'];
    $merchantId     = 1234;
    $password       = 'Hello';
    $txnType        = 10;   

    //Concatanate the values together
    $results = $merchantId . '|' . $password . '|' . $txnType . '|' . $primaryRef .'|' . $amount .'|' . $fp;
    // Hash the information
    $results = sha1($results);
    // Encode data as JSON
    $returnValue = 'jsonpCallback(' . json_encode(array('fingerPrint' =>$results)) . ');';

    // change the content type
    header('Content-type: application/javascript');
    echo $returnValue;
}
?>
```

and calling JQuery code -->

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Generate the UTC date time
    GenerateUTCDateTime();

    //Generate the fingerprint and pass the values from the three hidden fields - primary_ref, amount, fp_timestamp
    GetFingerprint($('[name=primary_ref]').val(), $('[name=amount]').val(), $('[name=fp_timestamp]').val());

    // function to ensure that all dates are returned as two digits
    // i = the number to checked
    // returns two digit number
    function addZero(i) 
    {
        if (i < 10) 
        {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }

    // function that generates the current date and time as UTC
    function GenerateUTCDateTime()
    {
        var dNow = new Date();
        var utc = new Date(dNow.getTime() + dNow.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
        var utcdate= utc.getFullYear() + addZero((utc.getMonth()+1)) + addZero(utc.getDate()) + addZero(utc.getHours()) + addZero(utc.getMinutes()) + addZero(utc.getSeconds());
        //asign the date and time to the hidden field fp_timestamp
        $('[name=fp_timestamp]').val(utcdate);
    }

    // function that populates the hiddent field with the fingerprint generated
    function GetFingerprint(primaryRefNo, amount, fp)
    {
        // make sure that the three input paramters are available, otherwise throw an error
        if (!primaryRefNo || !amount || !fp)
        {
            alert('Could not find the required values, please contact test@test.com');
            return;
        }

        // web service URL
        var webService = "https://vik-b-it.000webhostapp.com/intergration.php";
        // input parameters that are passed
        var parameters = JSON.parse('{"primaryRef":' + primaryRefNo + ', "amount":' + amount  + ', "fp":' + fp +'}');

        // make an ajax call to get the data
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: webService,
            data: parameters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
            success: function(data) {       
                $('[name=fingerprint]').val(data.fingerPrint);
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('Error has occured, please contact support@test.com');
            }
        });
    }  
});
```

Comment: Try adding a ? at the end of webService var? I don't see it anywhere else

Comment: Also - have you looked into 'same origin' policy? this may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the data you pass to ajax request is invalid

You expected JSON but you pass string

```
var parameters = "{'primaryRef':'" + primaryRefNo + "','amount':'" + amount + "','fp':'" + fp + "'}";
```

So try to change it to valid json
Here the hint

```
var parameters = {primaryRef: primaryRefNo, amount: amount, fp: fp};
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Like you pointed out I had to pass in a Json object.  I have updated my question with the solution code, if anyone else is interested.